# Extending .text section of executable fails

Tags: code-injection, instrumentation, portable-executable

Warning - it is rather long question.

**Background**

I'm working on my small project for instrumenting pe files. At the moment my main focus is to extend .text section of an executable. Not add a new segment, not modify the entry point, but really extend existing .text section.

My approach is very naive. I fully rely on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format and so I'm happy to hear suggestions on how I can improve. Moreover maybe you will spot something I've missed. For now I'm:

1. fixing all raw/virtual addresses of sections that are after .text
   section making sure they are aligned correctly,
2. fixing some
   fields in headers such as size of data, size of code, checksum,
3. iterating over every data dictionary and fixing all fields which
   have RVA.
   When comparing files in pe-bear everything seems to be correctly updated.

**Current state**

I am able to extend small project written by myself which use TLS, exceptions, imports, delay imports, sefe seh and resources. But I fail to extend real, big applications avaible on internet.

**Notepad++**

One of the applications which I'm unable to extend is Notepad. By this I mean that modified Notepad++ binary crashes. I've traced down a place which seems to be the reason.

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov ebx, dword ptr ss:[ebp+8] ; <-- 1) this argument in orginal is equal to 2. In permutated executable it is equal to some huge number
xor ecx, ecx
push edi
xor eax, eax
lea edi, dword ptr ds:[ebx*4 + 0x641fdc] ; <-- and so this causes ACCESS VOLATATION
```

Some screenshots:
x64dbg - orginal Notepad++ before 1). Base: 0x41000. The ebx will become: 0x2.
[image]
x64dbg - extended Notepad++ before 1). Base: 0x42000. The ebx will become: 0x00177FF4
[image]

0x146dde rva address is a relocation. Here is a screenshot of this relocation in orginal Notepad++
[image]
And in the modified one. Note that only the relocation value has changed from: 0x611fdc to 0x621fdc (which is expected behaviour):
[image]

And finaly screenshot of sections:
orginal:
[image]
modified:
[image]

Link to orginal Notepad++ binary: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v7.8.6/

Link to modified Notepad++ binary: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hokh4ulmtgn7om1/notepad%2B%2B.permutated.exe?dl=0

Comment: Just a thought: x64 executables have exception handling information stored in the LOAD_CONFIG directory.  This points to an IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY64 structure.  You might need to update one or more of these members.

Comment: this is x86 executable :/

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Looking closer at the binary, I can see SAFESEH is enabled which still means you want to check the load config directory (i.e. IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY32 structure) for RVA changes to the exception info.  At the very minimum, I'd think you'd want to update the SEHandlerTable which is a VA of an array of RVAs.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it. I'm updating the VA of SafeSEH because it's a relocation and I'm taking care of all relocations. Then I'm fixing all RVAs inside this table.

Comment: I didn't want to install notepad++ to access the original EXE, but your modified version of the binary is statically linked to the CRT.  The function that is failing is embedded within the CRT's initialization of the thread block which uses TLS and FLS for storage.  You appear to be failing on a global variablewhich is assigned a TLS index if not already assigned (

Comment: I didn't want to install notepad++ to access the original EXE, but your modified version of the binary is statically linked to the CRT.  The function that is failing is embedded within the CRT's initialization of the thread block which uses TLS/FLS to access the CRT's thread-data.  You appear to be failing on a global variable passed in by the 2nd outer function. Its possible it was not assigned a TLS index if not initialized to zero in your modified executable (but the original might be initialized to zero). I'm not a TLS expert, but maybe check your TLS Directory for adjustments?